# Table View Scrolling Causes Unexpected Results

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

My table view has a hidden image and when the user completes the level, this image becomes visible for the relevant cell. This process works with no issue.

Strangely, when i scroll the table view up and down, this hidden image begins randomly to appear on the other cells which belong to an incompleted level.

If I leave the view controller and get back, unexpected ones dissappear and if I start scrolling again, they come back.

Additionally, if all images are hidden (means there's no completed level), scrolling doesn't cause this issue. Here's the code piece I use:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellView.frame.height / 2
    cell.levelLabel.text = levels[indexPath.row]
    cell.lockingImage.image = UIImage(named: lockState[indexPath.row])

    if completeState[indexPath.row] == "true" {
        cell.completedImage.isHidden = false
    } 
    return cell
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a cell reuse issue. But without code, who can tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are doing:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.myImageView.isHidden = true

        return cell
    }
```

What you should do is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    if levels[indexPath.row].isLevelCompleted {
        cell.myImageView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.myImageView.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is because you are dequeuing the cell. Which means UITableView will use old cells. If you change the cell actively, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks Onur, I forgot to put the "else" statement. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @EmreKurtaran you are welcome Emre. if you have any further questions, you can reach me at any time

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not reset the image visibility to `false` in the `prepareForReuse` function of the cells, which leads to the image to be visible whenever the cell in question is reused.